# Can't understand why (n-1)choose(-1) equals zero.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I have tried to wrap my head around the idea but I can't seem to get it, and google yields no coherent explanation. Would appreciate some clarification about this.

Comment: Because there are no size (-1) subset of any set.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Answer (score 4):

It's seems more like a matter of definition but if for example you want Pascal's rule to work also for negative numbers then:

$${n \choose {-1}}={n+1\choose 0}-{n\choose 0}=1-1=0$$

Also as @user10354138 pointed out in the comments $n \choose k$ denotes the number of subsets of size $k$ in a set of $n$ elements so if we want to extend this to negative numbers it would only make sense if it would be 0 since there are 0 subsets of size -1.